# Java password protected webservice trough proxy server

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, proxy

I'm trying to call a pasword protected web service. When I use the server's IP address, it works fine:

```
public class MyWsClient extends CxfClientBase<MyWs> 
{
  public MyWsClient () 
  {
  super(  
      "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/somewebservice",
     ...
     );

     BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
     prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
     prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
     ...
  }
```

But I need a proxy server, if I want to use the server's DNS name. So, I added the following code:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

It relays the DNS name, but I get 401 authentication error from the web service.

Why doesn't work the authentication, when I use proxy server?